# Relative layout not getting resize under parent Frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have relative layout as child of frame layout. Its in the center of framelayout. But I want to resize it according to device width at runtime.

output:
[image]

In above image, blue background is my relative layout. I want it should be only 50% of screen width. Any help please.

Comment: Show your xml code please.

Comment: Can you post your xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to you `PercentRelativeLayout`, and put height and width percentage. Please follow this link for details 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html